# Using Intertiajs with Element UI

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, element-ui

I am using [Inertiajs](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-vue) 
with Laravel and also trying to use [Element UI](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu#navmenu) components but as i use Menu component i am having following error in console, I just used example as given in Element Ui Components as i was testing. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 different errors in there, both of them are with props.

1. I assume your component is taking the route as a prop, and you are also using the route as a method, which you might have put inside `methods: {}` which is not allowed. Make sure you rename your method route to something else.

Note: As a matter of fact you can't have any data coinciding with each other. your props, data, computed props and methods all should have unique names.

2. You are trying to use v-model on the props directly which won't work in Vue. if the prop is a primitive (Number, String, Boolean etc). but you can pass Object or an Array which can hold a reference to the data. This is because reactivity in Vue can't keep track of props when passed as primitives.

More on prop mutations here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow